# ISO 24711: How to calculate page yield for a combination cartridge product?

Tags: printer, standards, cartridge

Printer manufacturers list their cartridge page yields on their sites using the ISO 24711 standard. Now there are also products which are "bundles" of cartridges. For example, you could have a product that contains 3 black cartridges.

In that case, the page yield is simply 3 times that of the original cartridge. So for a 600 page cartridge 3-pack, that would be 1800.

However, there's also something called 'colour' cartridges. How would I get the proper amount of pages printed by a product containing `Y` yellow, `M` magenta, `C` cyan, `G` grey, and `B` black cartridges, according to ISO 24711?

I would hazard a guess the standard may have something to say about it, depending on how things are measured. (Is it 550 'random' pages empty the cartridge, or 550 pages 'covered' by text with its colour?).

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR** It's complicated, but your final guess is correct.

A colour page uses a mixture of all the inks. So, if you use the "recommended" 5% coverage **per colour**, you will get the rated number of pages for each of the cartridges. A standard mono "business letter" is about 5% coverage. A standard colour page has the same amount of each of the 4 colours. That means a total of 20% coverage.

So your guess of "550 pages 'covered' by text with its colour" is correct. If a cyan cartridge is rated at 550 pages, then 550 business letters printed in cyan will empty that cartridge.You also need to make sure that all colour corrections in the application and driver are turned off. If you don't, you can guarantee that your 5% cyan will contain some of the other colours as well. This is because no printer inks are "ideal" cyan - whatever that is.

One simple way of creating a 5% coverage page is to fill the page with a 5% tint of an ink colour. And remember to turn off those colour corrections - if the driver will even let you...

Inkjets make this much more difficult to evaluate than lasers, for 2 reasons. First, because of all the cleaning cycles they waste **far** more ink than lasers. Cleaning can be either user-initiated (when one or more of the jets fail) or automatic. Automatic cleans happen at every power-up, when the printer comes out of standby, and at various times during normal operation. In some cases it has been estimated that less than 50% of the ink ends up on the paper. So your inkjet cartridge may print only half of those 550 pages.

On top of that, many inkjets have more than 4 ink colours. The amount of, say, cyan and light-cyan used on a page is anybody's guess. While high-end applications like InDesign let you work in CMYK (as well as RGB and other colour spaces), no applications let you work in the printer's light-cyan or whatever other inks it has. Hence, creating a 5% light-cyan page is essentially impossible.